# How to merge image of many channels?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I'm trying use multi-channel file to training unet classify.

My dataset is 5 * 1-channel & 1 * 3-channel image, and I expected it can be 8-channel .npy file.

I use np.concatenate to merge, but it cannot apply on a 1-channel image. Here is my code:

```
for i in range(6):
  img = data[i]
  images.append(img)
img_batch = np.concatenate(images, axis=3)
```

So, it should expand 1-channel-image to 3-channel first, then concatenate, then to 18-channel .mpy file

```
Image.open("class1_image1.jpg").convert("RGB")   #expand 1-channel-image to 3-channel image
```

Is there a method to merge multiple images into a multi-channel .npy file without expanding 1-channel image?

Or 18-channel and 8-channel are the same file for unet classify task?

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the images (at least the 1-channel images)? It doesn't matter how many channels the images have or even if the images have different numbers of channels, but I'll do an example of merging two 3-channel images and one 1-channel image:

We can merge the images' RGB (or however many 3rd dimension channels) values with `numpy` by inserting the images into the 4th dimension (then summing over the 4th dimension).

First we have some images (doesn't matter how we get them, I just used Google images for this example), and make sure they're the same size:

```
from skimage import io as io
image1 = io.imread('https://www.allrecipes.com/thmb/c_2gXiAwkO6u1UJCY-1eAVCy0h0=/1500x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/54679_perfect-baked-potato-Rita-1x1-1-91711252bb3740088c8ea55c5f9bef1c.jpg')
image2 = io.imread('https://cdn.loveandlemons.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/baked-potato.jpg')
image3 = io.imread('https://www.southerncravings.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Crispy-Baked-Potatoes-7.jpg')

image1 = image1[:, 200:-200, :]
image2 = image2[:-60, :-60, :]
import numpy as np
image3 = np.sum(image3[:-300, :-100, :], axis=2)
```

`image1`:

[image]

`image2`:

[image]

`image3` (just 1-channel):

[image]

`image3` (after concatenating in the 3rd dimension, so 3-channels; described next):

[image]

We're going to have to expand the images that have fewer than the max number of channels in our list of images by using `numpy`'s `concatenate` function in the 3rd dimension:

```
import numpy as np
def make_list_of_images(images_list):
    list_of_images = []
    for _image in images_list:
        if len(_image.shape) == 2:
            _image.shape += (1,)
        if _image.shape[2] < np.max([_image_channels.shape[2] for _image_channels in images_list if len(_image_channels.shape) > 2]):
            _image = np.concatenate([_image for _ in range(np.max([_image_channels.shape[2] for _image_channels in images_list if len(_image_channels.shape) > 2]) - _image.shape[2] + 1)], axis=2)
        list_of_images.append(_image)
    return list_of_images
```

We're going to have to normalize the RGB (or 3rd dimension channel) values, so here is a function to do that:

```
import numpy as np
def normalize_rgb_values(rgb_values, max_value=1.0):
    norm_rgb_values = (rgb_values - np.mean(rgb_values)) / np.var(rgb_values)**0.5
    norm_rgb_values += abs(np.min(norm_rgb_values))
    norm_rgb_values *= (max_value / np.max(norm_rgb_values))
    return np.round(norm_rgb_values, decimals=0).astype(int) if max_value == 255 else np.round(norm_rgb_values, decimals=9).astype(float)
```

Here's the `images` `numpy` array of zeros we fill by enumerating through our `list_of_images` and inserting each `_image` into the 4th dimension:

```
import numpy as np
max_number_of_channels = np.max([_image_channels.shape[2] for _image_channels in list_of_images])
images = np.zeros((image1.shape[0], image1.shape[1], max_number_of_channels, len(list_of_images))).astype(float)
for _image_num, _image in enumerate(list_of_images):
    images[:, :, :, _image_num] = _image
```

And instead of concatenating, we can use `numpy`'s `sum` to merge the `images` (summing over the 4th dimension):

```
import numpy as np
summed_images = np.sum(images, axis=3)
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(normalize_rgb_values(summed_images))
plt.show()
```

Merged images (i.e. `summed_images`):

[image]

And here is the code altogether:

```
from skimage import io as io
image1 = io.imread('https://www.allrecipes.com/thmb/c_2gXiAwkO6u1UJCY-1eAVCy0h0=/1500x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/54679_perfect-baked-potato-Rita-1x1-1-91711252bb3740088c8ea55c5f9bef1c.jpg')
image2 = io.imread('https://cdn.loveandlemons.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/baked-potato.jpg')
image3 = io.imread('https://www.southerncravings.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Crispy-Baked-Potatoes-7.jpg')
image1 = image1[:, 200:-200, :]
image2 = image2[:-60, :-60, :]
import numpy as np
image3 = np.sum(image3[:-300, :-100, :], axis=2)

def make_list_of_images(images_list):
    list_of_images = []
    for _image in images_list:
        if len(_image.shape) == 2:
            _image.shape += (1,)
        if _image.shape[2] < np.max([_image_channels.shape[2] for _image_channels in images_list if len(_image_channels.shape) > 2]):
            _image = np.concatenate([_image for _ in range(np.max([_image_channels.shape[2] for _image_channels in images_list if len(_image_channels.shape) > 2]) - _image.shape[2] + 1)], axis=2)
        list_of_images.append(_image)
    return list_of_images

list_of_images = make_list_of_images([image1, image2, image3])

def normalize_rgb_values(rgb_values, max_value=1.0):
    norm_rgb_values = (rgb_values - np.mean(rgb_values)) / np.var(rgb_values)**0.5
    norm_rgb_values += abs(np.min(norm_rgb_values))
    norm_rgb_values *= (max_value / np.max(norm_rgb_values))
    return np.round(norm_rgb_values, decimals=0).astype(int) if max_value == 255 else np.round(norm_rgb_values, decimals=9).astype(float)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
for _image in list_of_images:
    if np.max(_image) > 1.0:
        plt.imshow(normalize_rgb_values(_image))
    else:
        plt.imshow(_image)
    plt.show()

max_number_of_channels = np.max([_image_channels.shape[2] for _image_channels in list_of_images])
images = np.zeros((image1.shape[0], image1.shape[1], max_number_of_channels, len(list_of_images))).astype(float)
for _image_num, _image in enumerate(list_of_images):
    images[:, :, :, _image_num] = _image

summed_images = np.sum(images, axis=3)
plt.imshow(normalize_rgb_values(summed_images))
plt.show()
```

If you're `open`ing the image files with `Image` `from` `PIL` you might have to make it a `uint8` `type` `numpy` `array` first:

```
import numpy as np
image = normalize_rgb_values(np.array(image).astype(np.uint8))
```